# R ggplot variable for text using two date variables in caption

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a project that I'm trying to update every week.

I want to have date range variables at the top of the project that I will use for different filters creating different tables.

I also want these variables to inform the caption in ggplot. Is there a way to take not one but two different variable strings and put them both into the ggplot caption?

You can see the problem at the bottom of the graph where is says:
"Week of date_range_begin date_range_end"

I kind of feel like this might be an easy solution for someone who has more of a true developer background?

```
date_range_begin <- "2021-07-11"
date_range_end <- "2021-07-17"

ggplot(data_frame, aes(x = spend, y = orders, color = factor)) +
  geom_point() + stat_smooth(method = 'lm', se = FALSE) +
  labs(title = "Title here", subtitle = "Orders ~ Spend") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, face = "bold")) +
  theme(plot.subtitle = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) +
  labs(caption = "Week of date_range_begin date_range_end")
```

[image]

Comment: `caption = sprintf("Week of %s, %s", date_range_begin, date_range_end)`?

Comment: that works! I've never heard of sprintf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way. The string is formed with `sprintf` to put the variables' values in the right places. An alternative could be `?paste`.

```
library(ggplot2)

date_range_begin <- "2021-07-11"
date_range_end <- "2021-07-17"

ggplot(data_frame, aes(x = spend, y = orders, color = factor)) +
  geom_point() + 
  stat_smooth(method = 'lm', formula = y ~ x, se = FALSE) +
  labs(
    title = "Title here", 
    subtitle = "Orders ~ Spend",
    caption = sprintf("Week of %s to %s", date_range_begin, date_range_end)
  ) +
  theme(
    plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, face = "bold"),
    plot.subtitle = element_text(hjust = 0.5)
  )
```

[image]

---

### Data

```
data_frame <- iris [3:5]
names(data_frame) <- c("spend", "orders", "factor")
```